# ASP.NET MVC localization: Get a resource instance

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resources

I'm trying to implement this [feature](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

I created a resource and set it `access modifier` to `public`, also `Custom Tool` property value to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`.

I'm trying to get an instance of this resource but I can't, either with strongly type the resource name nor with `Type.GetType("WebProject.Resources.Home.ViewModels.ResourceName1");`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like the way MVC is doing localization so I made it my way. You can check my tutorial here: http://kosev.blogspot.com/2010/06/tutorial-create-aspnet-mvc-localization.html

I'm using simple XML language files, then I have Translator class with caching + html helpers for easy translation in html views. Hope this helps.